Oracle SQL pattern matching using wildcards
I'm trying to search though a large list of postal codes in various countries
Specifically, I want to identify all Canadian entries USING A CASE STATEMENT.
after all spaces have been stripped out, Canadian Postal Codes should conform to this pattern:
[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]

Something like
CASE 
WHEN AD.AD_PCODE LIKE '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]' THEN 'CANADA'

does Oracle SQL support this sort of pattern matching? I know SQL does, but I cant find any references to doing this sort of thing with Oracle SQL.

"I know SQL does" - no in standard SQL LIKE only supports % and _,. But SQL Server does support this kind of pattern matching in LIKE. (But it doesn't support other regular expressions like some other DBMS do.)

"I know SQL does" does not make sense as Oracle's SQL is a dialect of SQL. Similarly SQL Server's SQL and PostgreSQL's SQL are different dialects of SQL but they are all "SQL". If you are talking about ANSI (or ISO) standard SQL then most SQL dialects are mostly compliant with the standard but I don't think any SQL dialects comply 100% with the ANSI standard as they all have individual syntax differences.

In Oracle we use REGEXP_LIKE:
CASE 
  WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(ad.ad_pcode, '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]') THEN 'CANADA'
  ...
END

